# C# How to iterate through list for individual API calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, json.net

From the following JSON data I want to put the station_code variables into a list. After this I want to use each station_code variable into a API URL call.

```
{
  "request_time": "2015-02-19T08:33:39+00:00",
  "stations": [
    {
      "station_code": "HWV",
      "atcocode": null
    },
    {
      "station_code": "HXX",
      "atcocode": null
    },
    {
      "station_code": "HAF",
      "atcocode": null
    }
]
}
```

This is the C# code I have attempting this

```
 dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        dynamic stations = array.stations;

        var test = JObject.Parse(json);
        var services = test.SelectTokens("stations[*].station_code").Select(t => (string)t).ToList();

        JArray items = new JArray();
        foreach (JObject station in stations)
        {
            items.Add(station["station_code"]);



        }

        int stationLength = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < stationLength; i++)
        {
            string localJson = get_local_departs("http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/station/"+ items[i] + "/live.json?app_id=03bf8009&app_key=d9307fd91b0247c607e098d5effedc97&train_status=passenger");

            dynamic localStationArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(localJson);
            dynamic departures = localStationArray.departures;
            dynamic localStationDeparts = departures.all;

            foreach (var depart in localStationDeparts)
            {
                //info put into data tables

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well why can't you convert that to a strong type and use that instead like

```
public class stations
{
  public string station_code { get; set; }
  public string atcocode {get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
 public DateTime request_time {get; set; }
 public IEnumerable<stations> Stations {get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

foreach(stations s in result.Stations)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s.station_code);
}
```

Comment: Because I need to put the station_code variables into a list so I can iterate thorugh them individually for each API call.